# How to mount an image file without root permission?

Tags: mount

Can I mount a file system image without root permission? Normally I would do:

```
mount -o loop DISK_IMAGE FOLDER
```

Without using sudo or setting the suid on `mount`, is there any suitable way to do this?

I know I can use `fusermount` with some ISO images, but that is pretty limited, even for ISO images, some of my images cannot be mounted, but `mount` always works.

Comment: If your `mount` binary doesn't require SUID permissions then you should be able to use [fakeroot](http://docs.openembedded.ru/fakeroot.html) without problems.

Comment: @faif `fakeroot` isn't going to help here: it pretends file ownership is different, but it can't give you permissions that you don't have, such as to call `mount(2)` when you aren't root.

Comment: @faif Mount *absolutely* requires root permissions. The potential consequences otherwise would be pretty disastrous.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96625/how-to-allow-non-superusers-to-mount-any-filesystem

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't mount anything that the administrator hasn't somehow given you permission to mount. Only root can call the `mount` system call. The reason for this is that there are many ways to escalate privileges through mounting, such as mounting something over a system location, making files appear to belong to another user and exploiting a program that relies on file ownership, creating setuid files, or exploiting bugs in filesystem drivers.

The `mount` command is setuid root. But if you aren't root, it only lets you mount things that are mentioned in `fstab`.

The `fusermount` command is setuid root. It only lets you mount things through a FUSE driver, and restricts your abilities to provide files with arbitrary ownership or permissions that way (under most setups, all files on a FUSE mount belong to you).

Your best bet is to find a [FUSE filesystem](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems) that's capable of reading your disk image. For ISO 9660 images, try both [fuseiso](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=CompressedFileSystems#fuseiso) and [UMfuse's ISO 9660 support](http://wiki.virtualsquare.org/wiki/index.php/UMview#umfuse) (available under Debian as the [`fuseiso9660` package](http://packages.debian.org/fuseiso9660)).

Comment: +1 for explaining that `sudo` (although it has the SUID bit set) only allows one to mount `fstab` entries. From this it follows that (a) the SUID bit makes sense, as a regular user can mount `fstab` entries (and is allowed to perform the `mount` syscall) and (b) that it is the `mount` utility's restriction to only allow `fstab` entries to be mounted by non-root users.

Comment: If you are working with floppy disk images, you can also use mtools to just write data to the image. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202706/create-a-virtual-floppy-image-without-mount

Comment: @David, has this now changed? The only entries I have in my `fstab` are for the rootfs and boot. To mount USB drives I look at `lsblk` and `mount` accordingly. I have not had problems doing this.

Comment: So how do you set up /etc/fstab to allow a user to mount then?

Answer (score 44):

The [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ManipulatingISOs) shows several ways of doing this. Here's one way. This requires the `udisks2` package to be installed.

First, create a 'loop device.' This will allow us to mount the image file.

```
$ udisksctl loop-setup -f $PATH_TO_IMAGE
Mapped file $PATH_TO_IMAGE as /dev/loop0.
```

Notice that it mapped the image at `/dev/loop0`. However, if the previous command had returned `/dev/loop1`, then you would replace `/dev/loop0` with `/dev/loop1` in all of the following commands.

You might need to run this command if the block device we created is not  automatically mounted with the previous command:

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/loop0
Mounted /dev/loop0 at /media/$USER/$IMAGE_NAME
```

You can look at files on the disk:

```
$ ls -l /media/$USER/$IMAGE_NAME/
```

You can unmount it when you're done:

```
$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/loop0
$ udisksctl loop-delete -b /dev/loop0
```

Comment: udevil was more convenient option

Comment: It worked on Ubuntu 16.04, but how? It seems to use loop devices which I'd expect to be `sudo` only. setsid or [related shenanigans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512291/how-is-ping-for-non-root-user-implemented-on-linux-distros/37518095#37518095)?

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 I'm not sure. The source code of the tool is [here](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/blob/master/tools/udisksctl.c). It seems to use DBus to talk to a daemon, but I don't know DBus or Glib that well.

Comment: Unfortunately `udisksctl loop-setup` required sys admin authentication for me on RHEL7. Don't know if that is the default config for RHEL, or my organization's hardening.

Comment: How to use this programmatically? Its annoying to have to parse the output of loop-setup to find what loop device was used. Also is there any way to set the autoclear flag such that the loop device is automatically deleted on unmount?

Answer (score 18):

You can use the FUSE module guestmount to mount several types of disk images. It's part of the guestfs ecosystem and won't require root permissions.

Take a look at the [man page](http://libguestfs.org/guestmount.1.html) for further details.

#### Examples

**1.** For a typical Windows guest which has its main filesystem on the first partition:

```
guestmount -a windows.img -m /dev/sda1 --ro /mnt
```

**2.** For a typical Linux guest which has a /boot filesystem on the first partition and the root filesystem on a logical volume:

```
guestmount -a linux.img -m /dev/VG/LV -m /dev/sda1:/boot --ro /mnt
```

Comment: Annoyingly, running guestmount on Ubuntu now requires some root access to read kernel images: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/759725

Comment: @Clément I would like to understand why libguestfs needs the a kernel image to to its job...

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 because libguestfs avoids needing root by starting a minimal Linux system inside a qemu virtual machine (anybody can start a qemu virtual machine without being root). To boot that machine, it needs some kernel and initrd.

Answer (score 5):

The way possible would be to add an `/etc/fstab` entry for the ISO with the 'user' parameter, like

`/test.iso /mnt/iso auto defaults,user 0 1`

But you usually need root access anyway to edit this file, so it's not very helpful.

Comment: The author specifically asks to mount without root permissions

Answer (score 2):

It is actually very easy to mount more or less whatever you want as a
normal user without root privileges, provided the right entry has
been created in `/etc/fstab`.

Of course, modifications to `/etc/fstab` require root privileges. But
a single entry can
be used with much flexibility to (u)mount many different files on
different mount points, without any further editing of `/etc/fstab`.

Here are two very short (5 lines + comments) Bash scripts that will do the job:

for mounting

```
#!/bin/sh
# usage: usmount device dir
# author: babou 2013/05/17 on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32008/mount-an-loop-file-without-root-permission/76002#76002
# Allows normal user to mount device $1 on mount point $2
# Use /etc/fstab entry :
#       /tmp/UFS/drive /tmp/UFS/mountpoint  auto users,noauto 0 0
# and directory /tmp/UFS/
# Both have to be created (as superuser for the /etc/fstab entry)
rm -f /tmp/UFS/drive /tmp/UFS/mountpoint
ln -s `realpath -s $1` /tmp/UFS/drive
ln -s `realpath -s $2` /tmp/UFS/mountpoint
mount /tmp/UFS/drive || mount /tmp/UFS/mountpoint
# The last statement should be a bit more subtle
# Trying both is generally not useful.
```

and for dismounting

```
#!/bin/sh
# usage: usumount device dir
# author: babou 2013/05/17 on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32008/mount-an-loop-file-without-root-permission/76002#76002
# Allows normal user to umount device $1 from mount point $2
# Use /etc/fstab entry :
#       /tmp/UFS/drive /tmp/UFS/mountpoint  auto users,noauto 0 0
# and directory /tmp/UFS/
# Both have to be created (as superuser for the /etc/fstab entry)
rm -f /tmp/UFS/drive /tmp/UFS/mountpoint
ln -s `realpath -s $1` /tmp/UFS/drive
ln -s `realpath -s $2` /tmp/UFS/mountpoint
umount /tmp/UFS/drive || umount /tmp/UFS/mountpoint
# One of the two umounts may fail because it is ambiguous
# Actually both could fail, with careless mounting organization :-)
```

The directory `/tmp/UFS/` is created to isolate the links and avoid clashes. But the symlinks can be anywhere in user space, as long as they stay in the same place
(same path). The `/etc/fstab` entry never changes either.

**VITAL WARNING:** 
*Mounting is restricted for good security reasons. Making it
more flexible may open doors for malicious software. I am not a
security expert and I would recommend that you open doors no more than
absolutely required ... using options to restrict what can be done
with the file systems that can thus be mounted.
If a knowledgeable contributor could comment further on security issues, it
might be useful.*

*Various options are available to restrict the use of file systems that are mounted, such as `noexec` which prevents execution of
binaries, or `nosuid`, and thus contribute to security. Actually, these options are added as default options when the options `user` or `users` are used, which is necessarily the case in what we do below. Think twice before you override these defaults.* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab

*Other options can be added for further protection. For example, the option* `owner` *in the* `/etc/fstab` *entry will let users deal only with files or devices they own. See* `man mount` *for a list of options:* http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.

*The use of this `/etc/fstab` entry can also be restricted through the user.group ownership of the directory (or directories) containing the symlinks.*

**Explanation**

This explanation was written before I realised I could simplify things to the two scripts above. I did not think of them right away partly because I have at hand a slightly more complex problem that they do not solve without some extra machinery. Thus my explanation may be a bit more intricate than it should, but I do not have the courage to rewrite it all from scratch.

The basic idea is to create entries in `/etc/fstab` that include the
option `user` or `users` so that a user can ask `mount` to do the
mounting specified in that entry by giving as argument the file to be
mounted or the mount point to use (but not both in my expérience).

You also need a proper entry to `umount` (which is a slightly different problem - see below). The option `user` is usually better than `users` since it restricts permission to `umount` to the user who mounted the file system, while `users` will allow that to all. Unfortunately the option `user` does not always work, and may entail some other steps to be made to work. This is discussed in [Option "user" work for mount, not for umount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76326/option-user-work-for-mount-not-for-umount).

First you add to `/etc/fstab` an entry such as:

```
/tmp/UFS/drive /tmp/UFS/mountpoint  auto users,noauto, 0 0
```

and use `/tmp/UFS/drive` as a symbolic link (or symlink) to whatever device or file
you wish to mount,
say a file containing the image of an ISO file system `/home/johndoe/john-image-file.iso`.

You also define `/tmp/UFS/mountpoint` as a symlink to the mount point you wish to use, say `/mnt/iso`.

You can then mount `john-image-file.iso` with the command :

```
$ mount /tmp/UFS/drive
```

This is sufficient on my Mageia Linux, since the use of loop devices
has now been made implicit, and no longer requires using `-o loop` explicitly. I do not know how general that is today. See 
[When mounting, when should I use a loop device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66075/when-mounting-when-should-i-use-a-loop-device)

This mounting appears in tables and commands :

```
$ df | tail -1
/dev/loop0       5,1G  5,1G     0 100% /mnt/iso
$ tail -1 /etc/mtab
/dev/loop0 /mnt/iso udf ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,utf8 0 0
$ mount | tail -1
/home/johndoe/john-image-file.iso on /mnt/iso type udf (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,utf8)
$ tail -1 /proc/mounts
/dev/loop0 /mnt/iso udf ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,utf8 0 0
$ tail -1 /proc/self/mountinfo
46 22 7:0 / /mnt/iso rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - udf /dev/loop0 ro,utf8
$ tail -1 /proc/self/mountstats 
device /dev/loop0 mounted on /mnt/iso with fstype udf
```

The mounting operation could work for any file or drive and requires only to
make a symbolic link from `/tmp/UFS/drive` to that file or to the device for the drive. Of course, another name and location could be chosen for the symbolic link, as long as it never changes.

Dismounting the file relies in the same way on appropriate use of symbolic links. In the case of a normal device corresponding to some harware drive,
you just use the same links.

However, files containing the image of a file system are mounted via a special kind of device called a loop device, automatically allocated when you mount the file.

To dismount the file, you need to refer to the loop device, not the file.
Hence you need in `/etc/fstab` an entry that matches both the loop device
used in `/etc/mtab`, here `/dev/loop0`, and the mount point, here
`/mnt/iso`.

You cannot create such an entry in advance since the loop
device may vary, as they are allocated dynamically. *Note that it is also
possible to use a fixed loop device, but it is inconvenient in other
ways. See
http://igurublog.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/how-to-allow-mounting-of-iso-files-by-a-regular-user/*  (*this blog actually inspired the reply here*).

However, you can find the name of the loop device, here `/dev/loop0`, by asking the system, like we did above in several different ways. Then our standard `/etc/fstab` entry can be made to point to the right loop device via the symlink `/tmp/UFS/drive`, and to the mount point as done previously with `/tmp/UFS/mountpoint`. This done, the file may be dismounted with any of the following commands (provided there is no ambiguity with `/etc/mtab`, which is a different problem):

```
$ umount /tmp/UFS/drive
$ umount /dev/loop0
$ umount /mnt/iso
$ umount /tmp/UFS/mountpoint
```

Since the two symlinks are needed only when the commands are issued,
they can be changed dynamically. So our single `/etc/fstab` entry
allows mounting any number of files, and umounting them in any
order, without root privileges.

Other references:

- [Mounting and modifying a loopback file without sudo/root, is it possible?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46423/mounting-and-modifying-a-loopback-file-without-sudo-root-is-it-possible)
- http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html

Comment: When fstab entries point to symlinks, can't they be exploited to mount anything without root, by just creating symlinks? Indirectly, isn't it just elevating `mount` command for every normal user?, and so the security issues associated with it? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: And recent versions of GNU/Linux distros (say debian jessie) will not provide a gui login when it detects an invalid entry in fstab. It falls back to console login session if the `device` or the `mountpoint` section of fstab doesn't point to a valid entry. The user has to login via console session and enter `startx` to explicitly start a display manager.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a note that this is completely possible to implement for a set of subprocesses, even if this has not been done yet.

A userspace mounter would emulate mounting using `LD_PRELOAD` or `ptrace` such as other utilities do to provide a fake root environment or transparent proxying.  The child processes have their system calls routed to hooks that pretend to be the kernel in userspace.

Here's another question that itself links to more: https://superuser.com/questions/1601311/fuse-fs-without-root-privileges-e-g-a-ld-preload-gateway-or-a-proot-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Package libguestfs-tools-c have guestmount command so

```
mkdir dvd    
guestmount -a image.iso -r -i dvd
```

df will show image.iso mounted

```
df
```

to umount we have :

```
guestunmount dvd
```

UPDATE 2020.03.25 :

Package archivemount seems a cool tool

https://pkgs.org/download/archivemount

example:

```
archivemount zentyal-6.0-development-amd64.iso tmp3/
```

Comment: 134 dependencies :-)

Answer (score -2):

if non-root user starts GUI, GUI would auto mount USB device. Even I removed x permision of mount for non-root users.