# How are setuid, suid, sudo, and su all related?

Tags: sudo, su, setuid

I have a feeling the `setuid` bit, the `nosuid` mount option, `sudo`, and `su` are all related given their names. 
But how do they relate to one another? 
Are some of them used in conjunction? 
 
If they are not, then why are their names so similar?

Comment: I think this is either a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65039/135943 or of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/135943.  Not sure which.  But if you read both of those, your multi-part question will be answered.

Comment: Actually even more relevant may be http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80350/135943.  By the way, "suid" just means "setuid"; those two have the exact same meaning.

Answer (score 9):

**setuid**: (set user ID upon execution) is a Unix/Linux *access rights flag* that allow users to run an executable with the permissions of the executable's owner. It is needed for tasks that require higher privileges than those which common users have, such as changing their login password.

**suid**: (saved user ID) is used when a program running with elevated privileges needs to temporarily do some *unprivileged* work. It changes its effective user ID from a privileged value (typically root) to some unprivileged one.

**nosuid**. When mount use this option then the file system doesn't allow set-user-identifier (*setuid*) or set-group-identifier (*setgid*) bits to take effect.

**sudo**: executes a command as *another user* but only if the original user is *allowed* to do it. (the user must be allowed previously in /etc/sudoers). It asks the user for their own password, making possible to authorize users to do tasks allowed only to root without revealing root's password.

**su**: This command allows the user to run a (new) shell / program as another user. The most common use of su is to *become root*. It asks for the password of the user you want to be, so only knowing that password it accepts the user substitution.

Comment: "become another user" meaning "run a (new) shell / program as another user". It does not change the permissions of running processes.

Comment: Yes. It's true. I'll change my answer.

Comment: So why have setuid bits if you have `sudo` or `su`? And if setuid bits are so important, then why don't see I see any of them when I use `ls` on important system executables?

Comment: If you issue a `ls -l /usr/bin/passwd` the result will show an `s` in the executable bit of the owner. That is the setuid bit

Comment: it's important because it can be assigned only to specific executables.

Answer (score 3):

"set user ID" is an important permission feature. `sudo` and `su` (and many other programs including `mount`) need this feature to work; some programs work partly without this feature (like `mount`), others (like `sudo` and `su`) do not work at all. This feature is related to files. Files exist in file systems only. `nosuid` disables this feature for all files in a file system (which makes especially sense for removable media).