# Why mount command works only with root

Tags: permissions, mount

When I type `mount <device> <folder>` I get message "mount: only root can do that", how so? if `mount` has `-rwsr-xr-x.` permissions?

Comment: This question was already answered here:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65039/why-does-mount-require-root-privileges

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mount as Normal user kindly make below entry in `/etc/sudoers` file Then you will able to mount

- edit `/etc/sudoers` file as root use `visudo -f /etc/sudoers`
- Mention below entry in file
- Suppose if you want to mount only paritcular partition then use below command

  ```
  username ALL=(ALL:ALL) /bin/mount partition /directory
  ```
- Suppose if you want some directory also use below command

  ```
  username ALL=(ALL:ALL) /bin/mount
  ```

  While mounting use `sudo` command infront of `mount`